# ASP.NET Page refresh instead update panel

Tags: asp.net, ajax

In my project there are number of repeaters in a page.Each repeater contains number of sub items.I want to Refresh the page without using the updatepanel control.How can achieve it through Ajax.Again i mentioning that the page contains a large number of controls.

Comment: You could explain this a little bit better.
What do you want to achieve? Which type of asp.net pages are you using? What have you done so far? Any code?

Comment: ASP.NET Web form application.There is a timer in master page.It refresh the page in every 5 seconds.I want to Refresh the page contents without using this timer.Instead use ajax functionality.But my problem is the page contains the large number of repeaters and controls

Comment: And why can't you use an update panel? It seems to me it is the correct thing in this situation since it's an asp.net web form app.

Comment: But it makes performance issue to the page.While updating some data in the  it makes issue

Comment: Can you please post some code. Don't get where it performs performance issue to the page. You just have to put an update panel where you want to update the info. not wrapping the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve I'm going to give you a couple of possible solutions to this problem whithout using update panels (which in my opinion, i think you should use in this case).

From the server side you can try:

```
Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
```

Client side:

After a page is rendered by the client browser there is only 2 possible ways to force a refresh. You can use JavaScript or Meta Tag.

- javascript:

  ```
  setTimeout("location.reload(true);", timeout);
  ```
- Meta tag:

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
  ```

You can set the refresh intervals on the server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your solution.I will update my issue with more clear as soon as possible